# Do I need to upload the main table first before uploading my supporting tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I'm working on a project where we have to use Visual Studios to load data from a .csv file into tables in SQL Server Management. I have 3 tables:

Accidents (ID, Severity, Description, WeatherID, RegionID) 
    Weather(WeatherID, Weather)
    Region (RegionID, State, Region).

These tables are created from the main table US Accidents (from Kaggle - not sure if allowed to put link to that here). All the data except the WeatherID, RegionID, and Region come from that main table previously mentioned.

My problem is that when I load the data into those tables and run `SELECT * FROM Accidents` the WeatherID and the RegionID fields are all NULL even though there is data in their respective tables. I have tried to look at similar questions on here (using INNER JOIN, using JOIN) and nothing works.

My question is:

1. Why does it show as NULL when there is data in the referenced table
2. Do I need to upload the main table (US Accidents) in order to stop those values from being NULL
3. If that IS what I need to do, how do I go about doing that and making sure that all the tables are properly connecting. This is assuming that the three tables that I have mentioned will also need to be connected to the US Accidents table as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Here are pics of how I set up my tables in Excel

[image: Accident table]

[image: Region table]

[image: Weather table]

Comment: Whether weather (pun intended) and region tables are populated is irrelevant from the accidents' table point of view. Null weather and region id values in the accidents table mean that weather and region information is not known for that accident. It is more important to determine if these fields are populated in the source csv file for accidents. If yes, then you made a mistake in the importing process.

Comment: You need to show us (a cut down) sample of the data to determine what is going wrong.

Comment: @DaleK Unfortunately the screenshots I tried to add are not showing. In Excel, I have my table set up as: Accidents (ID, Severity, Description), Region(RegionID, State, Region), and Weather (WeatherID).None of the tables contain information from other tables in the Excel files. Hopefully this comment helps and I'll continue trying to post the actual screenshots.

Comment: I was more meaning the CSV version - we need to see the actual data that is attempting to be imported, not a picture of it.

Comment: @DaleK Oh ok. Let me go and try to do that then

Comment: @DaleK I'm a little confused by what you want to see. Do you want me to open the .csv file in notepad and copy and paste that into my question?

Comment: @BrandiAlcox It appears that your accidents excel sheet does not have the missing data, which explains why it is not in your table

Comment: We want the smallest possible sample of your data, in text format, which will reproduce the issue. But it seems that Kevin might already have the answer for you.

Comment: @Kevin So, I need to add all the columns from both my Region and Weather tables to my Accidents table? Or just certain columns?

Comment: @Shadow Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @DaleK Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Really appreciate it!

Comment: Did something above help you you solve the issue? If it was just simple mistake feel free to delete the question. If you think the resolution details would help someone else you can self-answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. Why does it show as NULL when there is data in the referenced table - this could be because the relationships are not setup between the main table and the referenced tables
2. Do I need to upload the main table (US Accidents) in order to stop
   those values from being NULL - not necessarily. If you are splitting the US Accidents table into three smaller tables (Accidents, Weather, Region) then you do not have to load the main table
3. If that IS what I need to do, how do I go about doing that and making sure that all the tables are properly connecting. This is assuming that the three tables that I have
   mentioned will also need to be connected to the US Accidents table
   as well - you need to import the Weather and Region reference tables first, and then the Accidents table. Make sure that the WeatherID and RegionID values from the Weather and Region tables match the values in the Accidents table. For referential integrity you will want to create relationships between the Accidents table and the Weather and Region tables.

Here is documentation showing how to create relationships in SQL Server
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-ver15